# Unable to Install ATI Radeon HD 7560M graphic card driver on Ubuntu Gnome 14.10

Tags: drivers, gnome, ati, radeon, 14.10

I am using Ubuntu Gnome 14.10 64 bit on Dell Inspiron 3521. I have ATI Radeon 7560M HD Series Graphics Card. I tried installing ATI Graphics card in different ways.

1)Selecting fglrx from Additional Drivers under Software & Updates section

2)Selecting fglrx-updates from Additional Drivers under Software & Updates section

3)Downloaded latest ATI Driver (amd-catalyst-14-9-linux-x86-x86-64.zip) from AMD website and installed it.

Before trying every option, I uninstalled older drivers completely.

In every option, after reboot, all I got is a text console. Couldn't able to get into Display at all. Is there any driver working for Ubuntu Gnome 14.10 ? How can I get it and install it ?

The primary reason for me installing is the battery backup. Its hardy 40 mins on Ubuntu where as its 4+ hours on Windows. I want to install ATI Graphics card driver and disable the Discrete graphics card and enable only Intel graphics card so that battery back up will be better.

Please help. Thanks in Advance.

**Update**: This is the error I am getting

/usr/bin/X: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules/modules/extensions/libglx.so: undefined symbol: LoadExtension

Xinit: giving up

Xinit: unable to connect to X server: Connection refused

Xinit: server error

**Update2** : Tried amd-catalyst-omega-14-12-linux-x86-x86-64.zip but no luck

Comment: did you disable secure boot ? last time I installed the ati driver I had to disable secure boot in my bios. otherwise , what error message are you getting in the logs ?

Comment: Yes secure boot is off. I don't have an option to disable ATI driver in my bios.

Comment: I am using Ubuntu Gnome. It has only gnome-shell and no unity

Comment: can you log in as another user ?

Comment: Tried. Not much difference

Comment: Sounds as if you should file a bug report against X

Answer (score 0):

You're seeing the symbol lookup errors because the amd-catalyst-14-9-linux-x86-x86-64.zip and amd-catalyst-omega-14-12-linux-x86-x86-64.zip packages are only compatible with the LTS releases, 12.04 and 14.04. So one option would be to downgrade from 14.10 to 14.04.

However, the [release notes](http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMDCatalystOmegaLINReleaseNotes.aspx) for the RUN installer indicate that it is compatible with 14.10. It is a more complicated install, but with the driver being built for your system you won't get symbol lookup errors.

Before you start, be sure you have all of the build dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential cdbs fakeroot dh-make debhelper debconf libstdc++6 dkms libqtgui4 wget execstack libelfg0 dh-modaliases
```

Then download [amd-catalyst-omega-14.12-linux-run-installers.zip](http://www2.ati.com/drivers/linux/amd-catalyst-omega-14.12-linux-run-installers.zip) and follow [AMD's installation instructions](http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/Catalyst-Linux-Installer-Notes.aspx#Install).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Edit your GRUB file /etc/default/grub

old:  `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""`
fix:  `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="nomodeset"`

and save & exit.

```
$ sudo update-grub
$ sudo reboot    ### you need to reboot before doing next command
$ sudo apt-get install -y fglrx-update* --reinstall
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo reboot
```